# Get Error for submit button before send data to Server side(php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a text box or input to save Phone number, i want that Users Can Only be able to Enter 11 Numbers and Just can accept Numbers Not Characters.
how Check and show message.
how this is possible in client side Like JavaScript And then Sending To Server Side.

my code that it`s Incorrect:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function code(input){ 
    if(input.length != "11"){
        //return false;

        alert("Enter a Valid Phone Number");
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and in submit section:

```
<input type=submit border=0 value=" " Onclick=code(getElementById("Phone").value) />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `return false` after `alert` in validate condition, try this code

```
function code(input){ 
  if(input.length != "11"){
    alert("Enter a Valid Phone Number");
    return false;
  }  

}
```

### UPDATE

If you want to accept only 11 number then try with `RegEx`

```
 function code(input){ 
      if(input.match(/^[0-9]{11}$/)){
        return true;
      }
       alert("Enter a Valid Phone Number");
       return false;  
    }
```

submit button change `Onclick` to `onClick` with quote and use `document.getElementById("Phone").value` instead of `getElementById("Phone").value`

```
<input type=submit border=0 value=" " 
   onClick='return code(document.getElementById("Phone").value)' />
```

Comment: You can even remove the else if you want. If input.length is 12 it will skip the if statement and return true anyway.

Comment: @Girish Is my second part of code correct for your code? : <input type=submit border=0 value="OK" Onclick=code(getElementById("Phone").value) />

Comment: No, didn`t work. it is like before Nothing Changed. why?

Comment: i have added changes in `Update` section, and what is error show up in your browser console

Comment: Yeah Now correct But Your code has @Vinay Sharma`s mistake. it show error but then load page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66205/discussion-between-girish-and-iliya).

Comment: add `return` in onclick event `return code(document.getElementById("Phone").value)`, see in ans

Comment: thanks this is useful. the answer selected. please explain more about this match(/^[0-9]{11}$/)? "match-/-^-{ [ and $"
Thank you

Comment: `/^[0-9]{11}$/` this is **regular expression** `^` - start with, `[0-9]` means input only numeric digit and `{11}` input length and `$` end, more info http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: ouhhh i have a problem in this issue, i have 2 others Input Box how to write in OnClick?     `function code(input){ 
      if(input.match(/^[0-9]{11}$/)){
        return true;
      }
       //alert("Enter a Valid Phone Number");
    document.getElementById('ErrMsg').innerHTML = "شماره تلفن معتبر وارد نمایید"
       return false;
    
    else if (input.match(/^[A-Z]{15}$/))
    {
    return true;
    }
    else { document.getElementById('ErrMsg').innerHTML = "در وارد کردن نام و نام خانوادگی دقت نمایید"
       return false;  }
    
    }  
</script>`
what write in Onclick after Phone Message?

Comment: @Girish did you get my problem? check previous comment and answer quickly.thanks

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318753/use-two-function-in-onclick-event-with-parameterjs) my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script>
  function code(inputd)
  { 
    var phoneno = /^\d{11}$/;  
    if(inputd.match(phoneno))  
    {  

        return true;  
   }  
    else  
   {  
        alert("error");  
        return false;  
   } 
 }
 </script>
 <form>
  <input type="text" id='Phone'>
  <input type="submit" onclick=return code(document.getElementById("Phone").value);>
 </form>
```

Please try this hope it is helpful.

Comment: didn`t work. is this correct for your code:    <input type=submit border=0 value=" " Onclick=code(getElementById("Phone").value) />

Comment: Sorry there is one extra ( by mistake please check I updated my answer.

Comment: yeah this is useful But it has a big mistake. it show error but then load page and send data to server side and last it`ll be store. How to avoid this?

Comment: Please let me know so I can improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Keypress event to disallow user to enter any character other than number `(0-9)`.

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#Phone").keypress(function(){
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    value = value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
    jQuery(this).val(value);
  });
});
```

Now, in your validation script, check the length

```
function code(input){ 
 if(input.length != "11"){
  alert("Enter a Valid Phone Number");
  return false;
 }
 else {
  return true;
 }
```

}

Comment: i never use jQuery. please tell me what to do.please write Java Script Code. THanks

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery is very easy. Try with:

```
<input type='text' id='phoneNum' border=0 value="" />
<input type='submit' id='submitBtn' border=0 value="" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
   var phoneNum = $('#phoneNum').val();
   code(phoneNum);
   // other code
});
function code(input){ 
    if(input.length != "11"){
        //return false;

        alert("Enter a Valid Phone Number");
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

</script>
```