# Use Two Function in Onclick Event with Parameter(JS)

Tags: javascript

This is my Two Functions with parameters:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 function code(input){ 
  if(input.match(/^[0-9]{11}$/)){
  document.getElementById('ErrMsg').innerHTML += "Phone Is Valid"
    return true;
  }
   document.getElementById('ErrMsg').innerHTML += "Enter Valid Phone Number"
   return false;
 }
  function codee(input){ 
  if(input.match(/^[a-z]{11}$/)){
  document.getElementById('ErrMsg').innerHTML += "Name is Valid"
    return true;
  }
   //alert("Enter a Valid Phone Number");
   document.getElementById('ErrMsg').innerHTML += "Enter Your Valid Name"
   return false;
   }
  </script>
```

my JS code that is below:

```
 <input type=text size=12 name=lname id=lname/>
 <input type=text size=12 name=Phone id=Phone/>
 <input type=submit border=0 value=OK  onclick='return code(document.getElementById("Phone").value)' />
```

how can i use two function in onclick of form?

Comment: "this problem" What problem? There is no description of a problem in your question.

Comment: toh problem kya hai ??(what is  the problem ?)

Comment: the problem is obvious
how can i use two function with parameter in onclick of form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call a single new method that collects the form inputs and checks them one at a time:

```
function validate() {
    var isValid = true;

    isValid = isValid && code(document.getElementById('Phone').value));
    isValid = isValid && codee(document.getElementById('lname').value));

    return isValid;
}
```

Your button changes to:

```
<input ... onclick="return validate();" />
```

Comment: More info on bitwise AND assginment operator here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_AND_assignment

Comment: @PoelincaDorin: Thanks for the link.. after you posted it though I decided I didn't like its usage here.

Comment: I didn't liked it either, however i always find it useful to post these kinds of links in the answer as it gives new programmers an entry point to the docs :)

Comment: yeah thanks, with a bit changes it`s correctly usable.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 function callBoth(input){ 
     return code(input) && codee(input);
 }

  </script>
```

Whether you AND or OR is up to your logic.

In your button:

```
 <input type=submit border=0 value=OK  onclick='return callBoth(document.getElementById("Phone").value)'/>
```

---

Based on your comment, you need to change your code like so:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 function callBoth(){ 
     return code(document.getElementById("Phone")) && codee(document.getElementById("lname"));
 }

  </script>
```

and your button

```
 <input type=submit border=0 value=OK  onclick='return callBoth();'/>
```

Comment: and what about lname? how to do it?
like this:
onclick='return code(document.getElementById("Phone").value);''return code(document.getElementById("lname").value);'

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to, as it does not feature in your question.  If this is for form validation, I would recommend looking at a plugin such as jquery validate, as this will make this a lot simpler for you.

Comment: yeah this is form validation. but in your code 
`callBoth(document.getElementById("Phone").value)`
this is just doing for "phone", what about for "lname"?
this is problem?